# Dynamically expand and collapse a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a bootstrap table for which when a user clicks on the button placed on the first column, the specific row gets expanded and more details are shown.

As reference, I am trying to achieve something similar to:

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

But, I do not plan on using the DataTables framework.

The table should not contain the details of all rows on page load. Basically when the button gets clicked I want an ajax request to be sent (an ajax loading screen will appear using the beforeSend function) and when the success ajax function gets executed then the specific row should get expanded with the details fetched via ajax and of course the loading screen overlay will be hidden). Then, when the button relevant to the expanded row gets clicked, the row should get collapsed.

I am just looking for a get started guide for this implementation.

Can you guys please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question! I would be glad to help you out.

**First**- An XML File (`database.xml`) to call your information from (expand as necessary):

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<database>
   <row id = '1'>
      <user>
          <name>Bob</name>
          <joined>10-10-2019</joined>
      </user>
   </row>
   <row id = '2'>
      <user>
          <name>Fred</name>
          <joined>10-11-2019</joined>
      </user>
   </row>
</database>
```

**Second**- A php file with the table (`index.php`):

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
          <?
          $users = simplexml_load_file('database.xml');
          foreach ($users-row) as $row {
             echo '<tr class = "row '.$row['id'].'">'
             echo '<td class = "expand"><div role = "button" class = "expand-button '.$row['id'].'">Expand</div></td>'
             echo '<td class = "username">'.$row->name.'</td>';
             echo '</tr>';
          }
          ?>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Third**- A JavaScript file with the XMLHTTPRequest to call a php file (`app.js`):

```
const getClass = (c) => document.getElementsByClassName(c);
for (let i = 0; i < getClass('expand-button').length; i++) {
   getClass('expand-button')[i].addEventListener('click', expand, false);
}
function expand(e) {
   let xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         getClass('row '+e.target.className.split(' ')[1]).innerHTML += xhr.responseText;
      }
   };
   xhr.open('GET', 'retrieveUsers.php?rowId='+e.target.parentElement.className.split(' ')[1], true);
   xhr.send();
}
```

**Fourth**- (and finally!) the php file to handle the request:

```
<?
$rowId = $_GET['rowId'];
$users = simplexml_load_file('database.xml');
foreach ($users-row) as $row {
   if ($row['id'] === $rowId) {
      echo '<tr class = "expanded">';
      echo 'Username: '.$row->name;
      echo '<br />Joined: '.$row->joined;
      echo '</tr>';
   }
}
?>
```

Tell me if this works

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I am not using php, but it gave me an overview of what I have to do. I have managed to set up a table for which rows can be expanded and collapsed based on mockup data as a start. I guess what I really wanted to figure out was what expanding a table row actually means from html point of view. Now I am basically appending a tr element with a td with colspan which in turn contains another table with a fixed layout and for which td elements have the style property "word-wrap: break-word;" because this table contains log entries and some of them are very long.